# Independent continuous random variables have almost surely no tie

Tags: probability-theory

> Let $X_1,X_2,...$ be independent random variables with continuous distribution functions $F_1,F_2,...$. Then
>   $$(i)\quad P\left( \bigcup_{j\neq k} \{X_j=X_k\}\right)=0
> \\(ii)\quad F_1=F_2=... \implies P\left( X_{\pi(1)}<...<X_{\pi(n)}\right)=\frac{1}{n!}$$
>   for any permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,...,n\}$.

I honestly tried but can't get much out of it. The only noteworthy part of my attempt might be to prove that the complement $\left(\bigcup_{j\neq k} \{X_j=X_k\}\right)^c = \bigcap_{j\neq k} \{X_j \neq X_k\}$ has probability 1 and using independence to write the probability of that intersection as a product. However, this didn't lead me very far.

I'm thankful for any help.

Comment: Can you show that $P(X_1=X_2)=0$?

Comment: @Did Ah, yes, I managed to prove it and using that $$P\left( \left(\bigcup_{j\neq k} \{X_j=X_k\}\right)^c \right)= P\left( \bigcap_{j\neq k} \{X_j \neq X_k\}\right)=\prod_{j\neq k} \underbrace{P\left( \{X_j \neq X_k\}\right)}_{=1} = 1$$

Comment: That, or, more simply, $$P\left(\bigcup_{i\ne j}\{X_i=X_j\}\right)\leqslant\sum_{i\ne j}P(X_i=X_j)=0.$$

Comment: Right, thanks. I still couldn't figure out the second claim. Could you give me a hint for that as well?

Comment: Hint: Symmetry.